# How to weighted sample in Presto SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

Table may look like the below:

| UID | Some measures |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 |
| 2 | 300 |
| 3 | 100 |
| 4 | 50 |
| 5 | 50 |

I want to use SQL to sample based on the weight of the measure, let's say we want to sample 1 UID, then there should be 50% chance that the UID =1 got sampled.

Basically, implementing the pandas sample(pd.sample(weight = 'some measure') function using sql

pandas sample function:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

Comment: What is expected output and why (i.e. formula)?

Comment: Clarified! Thanks!